# DNN architecture for regression with small inputs, large output

Tags: regression, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

**TL;DR what DNN architecture for 1xn (n<50) tensor to 256x256x6 tensor regression?**

I'm facing a supervised regression problem where I need to predict the outcome of the numerical simulation of a physical process. Each simulation takes as input a 1xn tensor of features ($n = 10-50$) and outputs a 256x256x6 tensor of real numbers. There is no randomness involved in the simulations and the input-output map is bijective. My main goal is prediction accuracy vs. a test set, with sub-percent RMS prediction error being the overall goal. My dataset contains 100k well-distributed samples.

It looks like some kind of CNN could work, given also the structure I expect in the output samples, but most examples I'm aware of run "in reverse" i.e. start from a NxNx3 image and evolve into an array of outputs. This prevents the use of transfer learning approaches.

What I have tried:

- classical ML approaches in scikit-learn using a MSE metric (kernel ridge regression, SVM, XGBoost): extremely poor results ($\sqrt{MSE}$ comparable to output magnitude), apparently no impact of tweaking hyperparameters
- shallow, fully connected NN with Dropout with Keras: regression plateaus early with $\sqrt{MSE}$ very large, no amount of tweaking seems to solve the issue

I'm a complete novice in practical deep learning so I'm a bit at a loss over what architecture to start with for this problem. Any help or pointers to where to look would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you'll need some sort of a [Generative adversarial network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network), see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.1784

Comment: @J.Delaney Thank you, the paper you linked is useful. However, if I understand correctly, a CGAN works as a classifier i.e. one would generate an output that belongs to a certain feature class. How would one adapt it to regression tasks?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding your task. What exactly are your inputs and outputs? Is the input a `1 * n`-sized tensor, and the output is `256 * 256 * 6`?

Comment: @Sean yes that is the case, I edited the question for clarity.

Comment: How do you know that there is no randomness?

Comment: @Dave the result of these simulations is fully deterministic if the input it known; repeated simulations with the same set of inputs return the same output samples, with minimal sample variance consistent with very small finite-precision errors introduced by the computation process.

Comment: Then you have a perfect predictor. Why use any kind of deep learning?

Comment: @Dave because the simulation process is very expensive computationally, while I hope a DL approach would give a reasonable approximation of the output while cutting the prediction time significantly. For context: even if I quantize the input tensor to say 128 values per cell, the total number of simulations required to fully span the population is $2^{7\cdot 50}$.

Comment: @gunport987 Sorry but I'm still confused. As Dave mentioned above, if your input-output mappings are (almost) fully deterministic, I'm not sure if deep learning is going to do you any good. Is there any reason you think that a DL approach would be more computationally efficient? Because if you want anything useful using DL then it's usually going to be computationally expensive.

Comment: @Sean the issue is with the calculation time required to generate samples. What I'm looking for is effectively a metamodelling-type  solution where, at the expense of a significant initial investment in sample generation and algorithm training, I can thereafter sample the input feature space at will and get the corresponding output with the prediction time $t$ being significantly less than a typical sample generation time $\tau$.

Comment: @Sean Another motivation is deployability: each of the 100k samples that make up my training set was generated on a cluster where it took approx 300s computation time. However, I would like to deploy the prediction algorithm on user machines with the computational power of a typical PC and get a result in human times. Since prediction times on a DNN tend to be low even for fairly complex models, this would be ideal for my case (most of the computation effort was "frontloaded" so to speak on the initial machine).

Comment: @Sean I expect this approach would be feasible in the first place since I expect the map on the input and output manifolds to be smooth, hence a DNN should be able to infer the effect of small deviations from a known feature sample on the output. The reason why simpler metamodelling approaches based on polynomial fitting don't seem to work is the highly nonlinearity and topological structure of the input represented by the  1xn tensor.

Comment: To be frank I still don't fully understand what you're trying to do, but if you're just trying to train a model to receive `1 * n`-sized inputs and map them to their corresponding `256 * 256 * 6` outputs, I would try and just use a linear projection to make the input shapes appropriate. You'd have to use some sort of padding on the inputs though, since I'm assuming that each sample has varying values for `n`.

Comment: @Sean thank you for the suggestion, can you perhaps expand a bit on it and turn it into an answer? For example, when you say "linear projection", what do you mean? To create a fully connected layer with linear activation function? Also, what steps do you envisage after that, to use an existing model like pix2pix or a roll your own, and in that case which architecture you see as being a good starting point (autoencoder, resnet, gan...?)